git lfs clone -- too large dir
I am a rookie about git lfs.
I feel confused about git lfs clone.
Because I use that command. I find I need to download double size of before.

Actually, My file is about 26 G, but .git dir seems to be 26G also after using git lfs.
I don't know if it is normal.
If you can give me related docs, thanks very much

models is your working directory so normal to have it. In the .git folder it should be in the lfs cache folder (and not in the objects one). So it is the cache of lfs files downloaded by git. That's normal and the only things that you can do is clearing it from time to time with git lfs prune. The only goal of lfs is to not download all the versions of these files when cloning but on demand when you need them.
